# Nutch Error: JAVA_HOME is not set

Tags: java, ubuntu, nutch

I followed this tutorial http://saskia-vola.com/nutch-2-2-elasticsearch-1-x-hbase/ When I finally tried to run Nutch `sudo bin/nutch inject urls` I got this error

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
```

but when I echo JAVA_HOME it returns

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

and it is also in /etc/environment

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
```

and also I added line to end of file ~/.bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

but it still returns this error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the command as root user, so the environment variables the application sees are the one's visible for root user not your user. Just check that the root has a JAVA_HOME environment variable set or run the program as your user, if possible.

You can try `sudo -E bin/nutch inject urls`

As the sudo manual says, 
-E, --preserve-env
Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables. The security policy may return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

Comment: As user I have permission denied. So i run sudo -i to switch to root and set file .bashrc with the same JAVA_HOME in root home and run bin/nutch inject and it works, but when I use sudo bin/nutch inject I get the same error about JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the full JDK is there not only the JVM. you can also override this by export JAVA_HOME=YOUR_PREFERED_JDK_PATH in  .bashrc file in you home directory.

Comment: I ran this export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 and source ~/.bashrc as root and It acted just like I described in comment on the first answer

Answer (score -1):

Probably you didn't set java path in `/etc/environment`. Try given command.

```
sudo vi /etc/environment
```

and then set Java path

```
JAVA_PATH=/give your java path here/
```

You can check java path by using `$JAVA_HOME`, and then use

```
sudo -E bin/nutch inject urls
```